# Графическое приветствие-заставка при загрузке

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Изначально установлена *Ubuntu 16.04 server* с оконным менеджером *icewm* и десктоп-менеджером *slim*.

Хочу добавить графическую заставку при загрузке, чтобы скрыть загрузочные оповещения *systemd*.

Где расположена и как настраивается такая возможность?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для задания картинки в экране загрузчика необходимо:

1. В файле  /etc/default/grub прописать строки:

   GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x768
   GRUB_BACKGROUND="/<Полный путь>/<Файл картинки>.jpg"
2. Запустить (с правами root) :

   update-grub
3. Перезагрузиться

Следует отметить, что grub понимает не все типы графических файлов. Полный список - в руководстве. Размер изображения задаётся в соответствии с возможностями драйвера дисплея, используемого при загрузке. Там тоже - не всё возможно...

Comment: дополните, пожалуйста, ваш ответ содержимым комментария.

Comment: @Sergey Спасибо за ответ я нашел, что оказывается мне нужен был Plymouth. https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Plymouth/